# I am getting an error in flutter setup in android studio in windows, i already updated and having latest version of flutter and android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, setup-project

[image: This is what i am getting while creating flutter project]
After completing all steps like SDK download, path setup in windows getting this error in flutter setup.

This error is occuring before creating flutter project.

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.9.2. Because flutter_tools depends on test >=1.16.0-nullsafety which requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 2.11.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because flutter_tools depends on test >=1.16.0-nullsafety which requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 2.11.0, version solving failed.)

[image: Image of Error]

Comment: Did you get this while running pub get? And also please paste your pubspec.yaml

Comment: Downgrade your test package or update dart version

Comment: My setup is having latest flutter version.

Comment: Flutter 1.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d408d302e2 (4 days ago) • 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
Engine • revision 5babba6c4d
Tools • Dart 2.9.2

Comment: @Deepanshu did you resolve the issue? I get the same error message.

Comment: @Heikkisorsa  No, this is still an error, i am still trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your pubspec file. If you have tried all possible solutions and can't figure out the issue, I would say to try and reinstall it.